# declare member of struct as a pointer in c and use it

Tags: c, pointers, struct, contiki

- I have a `uint8_t *C = malloc(24*sizeof(uint8_t));`
- I need to send some integers and this *C to another node(in ad hoc network). So I am going to use a struct

  ```
  struct fulMsg {
    int msgType;
    int msgCount;
    //uint8_t *CC;     
  } fulMsg_t;

  typedef struct fulMsg fulMsg_tt;`
  ```
- there is a method called `packetbuf_copyfrom(X, sizeof(X));`  in my api(contiki). If I create struct like this  `struct fulMsg *fmsg = &fulMsg_t;` I can use the above method like this `packetbuf_copyfrom(fmsg, 8);` and from the other end I can easily get those two values.
- So my problem is when I am going to apply same thing to that pointer it is not working the network simulator that I am using suddenly be crashed (I think there is a segmentation fault). I can't initialize size of *C in the struct no. And how correctly do this `fmsg->CC = C;`
- At the other end this is how I receive this struct is `struct fulMsg *r_fmsg = &fulMsg_t;` and `rfmsg = (fulMsg_tt *)(packetbuf_dataptr());`. So I can easily get values from other end. (No need to do ntoh and hton, but it is ok if this really needs that)
- In simple what I want to do is send the value of *C contain and some other integers to another node. How can I correctly do this.

Comment: fundamentally what you are doing should work but really we cant help. Your question says "I have a bunch of code that shunts around pointers to various dynamically allocated data etc.. and then it crashes. Why?" We dont know why. We need a simple example. Or you need to put printf code in there to see where exactly it dies or use a debugger

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with contiki, and there doesn't seem to be much handy documentation on it, but from what I did find, it doesn't look like the function is smart enough to know what parts of your struct are pointers, so my guess is it's not designed for that.  I think you will have to make a struct that directly contains the full array, e.g.,

```
struct fulMsg {
  int msgType;
  int msgCount;
  uint8_t CC[24];
} fulMsg_t;

typedef struct fulMsg fulMsg_tt;
fulMsg_tt msg;
uint8_t *C = malloc(24*sizeof(uint8_t));
// Do whatever with this array, then
msg.msgCount = 24; // or whatever
memcpy(&msg.CC, C, 24*sizeof(uint8_t));


packetbuf_copyfrom(&msg, sizeof(fulMsg_tt));
```